# Prompt not working when logged in as specific user

Tags: 11.10, ssh, openssh, putty, prompt

Hello I am running ubuntu 11.10 and access it via ssh with putty.
My problem is that when I log in I get the prompt

```
username@server.com:~$
```

and my arrow keys do what the y are supposed to. When I try to login in as another user account I made all I get is this as the prompt it never says the directory or anyting

`$`

Also when ever I try to use the left, right, up or down arrow I get a character like this

```
^[[A
```

Is this a bug in putty or did I just not set the account up right?

Answer (score 2):

This happens if you created the user with the command

```
    useradd
```

You then need to create the users home directory and copy the files from /etc/skel into it. They are .bash_logout .bashrc  and .profile

If you use

```
    adduser
```

this is all done automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the used shell . Try to type `bash` after you get logged. If it wirks, then set bash as the default interpreter for your user.